# How can response files from server

Tags: java, servlets, multipartentity

I am sending files(images , pdfs , ...) from android phone to server which is a servlet I am using the HttpClient and HttpPost . (multipart data)

Here is my code for sending the post request

```
String postURL = //server url;

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(postURL);

ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes,"file_name_ignored");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("source", bab);
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

I want to send and recieve files(many files) as multipart.
I can send from client bu cant send from server to client in the servlet.( in the response).

How can i do this? (client requests get files and how can server response list of files like all in one capsule).

Comment: Make a zip file out of them?

Comment: Am I correct to assume you want a client to download many files at once? If so, you can only send 1 file back per request. So if you want to send everything in 1 request, you need to create a zip file of all your files and have your servlet return that zip file. There are plenty of examples of that available.

Comment: yes. but a client recives files specification (files have ids,names,...  refer to any project) in json . how can send json+ files ?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are e.g. using Jersey on the server you could use :
org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart
as response body.

```
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public Response multiPartResponder(){
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    BodyPart bodyPart = new BodyPart(myFileInputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart);
    return Response.status(OK).entity(multiPart);
}
```

You could then either use one body part the your JSON payload and one for your file content, or annotate your file body part with a custom header which contains your meta data.